# Python: Access base class "Class variable" in derive class

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to access a class variable from the base class in the derived class and I am getting a no `AttributeError`

```
class Parent(object):
    variable = 'foo'

class Child(Parent):
    def do_something(self):
        local = self.variable
```

I tried using it as `Parent.variable` but that did not work either. I am getting the same error 
`AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'Child variable'`

How do i resolve this

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://ideone.com/79GXNu)

Comment: Please describe your issue more clearly. The code sample above seems fine. Also, python class inheritance has been covered very well here on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Your code and your error don't match. In the code you've shown you are using the attrbiute name `variable`, however the error says Python can't find the name `Child variable`. Please post the _actual_ code you are using _verbatim_.

Comment: Your code works without error for me. When I replace `local = ...` by `print(...)`, then `Child().do_something()` prints "foo".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. The code below assumes you have an initialization method, however.

```
    class Parent(object):
        variable = 'foo'

    class Child(Parent):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def do_something(self):
            local = self.variable
            print(local)

    c = Child()
    c.do_something()
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

The code shown below should work on both Python 2 & 3:

```
class Parent(object):
    variable = 'foo'

class Child(Parent):
    def do_something(self):
        local = self.variable

c = Child()

print(c.variable)  # output "foo"
```